# Step by step process for Maven integration with Eclipse 3.5

Tags: eclipse, maven, m2eclipse

Would any one give me some source from where I can found step by step process for Maven integration with Eclipse 3.5? Or can any one explain?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a complete tutorial (and [a video](http://www.celinio.net/tutorials/MavenTuto2.htm)) in this [blog post](http://www.celinio.net/techblog/?p=734):

> Create a Maven project and import it with m2Eclipse
>
> The `m2Eclipse` plugin for Eclipse enables you to work with Maven projects in Eclipse.
> For instance, it is possible to run the `INSTALL` maven plugin from Eclipse to generate the `WAR` archive in the `target` folder.

For installing the m2Eclipse plugin itself, see "[Tutorial: Install m2eclipse into the Eclipse IDE](http://fusesource.com/docs/router/1.4/getting_started/Tutorial-InstallM2eclipse.html)", or "[Tutorial: GWT, Maven and Eclipse with M2Eclipse](http://claudiushauptmann.com/tutorial-gwt-maven-and-eclipse-with-m2eclipse.html)" using http://m2eclipse.sonatype.org/update/ as an update site.

Comment: @Sanju: Note, to know more about m2eclipse, you can watch http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-6G00KFONrw&feature=player_embedded, a  session, presented by Sonatype developer Igor Fedorenko at EclipseCon 2011, detailing what's new in m2eclipse 1.0.

Comment: the second to last link appears to be broken.

Comment: as does the third to last link.

Comment: @antony.trupe yes, that kind of happen... You might find a trace of that tutorial in http://gwt-maps-gxt.googlecode.com/svn-history/r90/trunk/gwt-maps-gxt-parent/gwt-maps-gxt/src/site/apt/getting-started.apt though.

Answer (score 1):

May be you can take a look into the official [book about m2eclipse.](http://www.sonatype.com/books/m2eclipse-book/reference/)